# SQL query to SUM the column data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
 FMT               price

MT1              606.99
MT2              238.91
MT3              316.54
MT4              371.42
MT5              124.95
```

How do i get total price for all MT1,2,3,4,5 using query?

Comment: Where does FM1,2,... come in for the table you gave?  Are you asking for a sum of all records in the `price` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE)
FROM thisTable
WHERE FMT IN ('MT1','MT2','MT3','MT4','MT5');
```